# How do I get the git init command to be a valid command on my server

Tags: git, version-control

I have installed git on my server.

When I try to do git init, it says git command 'init' not found. Does anyone know why? or if there is a solution to this.

--EDIT--

I have tried to install it with yum and then uninstall it from recommendation

```
# yum remove git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: git
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * extras: mirrors.ukfast.co.uk
 * updates: centosr4-msync-dvd.centos.org
Package(s) git available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Is this maybe a problem of my mirrors not having the files for me to install git?

below is the problem that I get when trying yum install git-core

```
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
epel/gpgkey                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.5 kB     00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 261, in main
    return_code = base.doTransaction()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 410, in doTransaction
    if self.gpgsigcheck(downloadpkgs) != 0:
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 510, in gpgsigcheck
    self.getKeyForPackage(po, lambda x, y, z: self.userconfirm())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3519, in getKeyForPackage
    keys = self._retrievePublicKey(keyurl, repo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3484, in _retrievePublicKey
    keys_info = misc.getgpgkeyinfo(rawkey, multiple=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 377, in getgpgkeyinfo
    raise ValueError('No key found in given key data')
ValueError: No key found in given key data
```

Comment: Give the `EXACT` error message.

Comment: Do any git commands work, `git clone`, etc.?  Sorry, just want to get the easy stuff first.

Comment: It says git command 'init' not found. Then it lists all of the other git commands as valid commands

Comment: git --version
Usage: git COMMAND [OPTIONS] [TARGET]
 git command '--version' not found: commands are:
  add archimport bisect branch checkout cherry-pick clone commit
  count-objects cvsimport diff fetch format-patch log ls-remote
  merge-one-file octopus parse-remote prune pull push rebase relink rename
  repack request-pull reset resolve revert sh-setup status tag verify-tag

Comment: What is your server? i.e. what OS? Also, what does `which git` tell you?

Comment: This is a superuser.com question, guys!

Comment: which git gives me /root/bin/git. The OS is CentOS 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to change repository and yum install git-core. Will ask a question how to do that

Comment: You gave the bounty to yourself?

Comment: Not as far as I know?.. I just answered it myself as no one was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go on, but the most logical explanation would be for your PATH to not be set correctly

Answer (score 1):

On early debian distributions *git* was the package name for GNU Interactive Tools. So when you did a

`apt-get install git`

you installed that one instead of the expected distributed revision control system. It was named *git-core* at this time. So try to do

`apt-get remove git && apt-get install git-core`

to be able to use the git command you want. See also the [debian package description](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/git)

Maybe this is what is going on.

Comment: it says apt-get command not found. I used Yum to install it

Comment: -1 for giving a solution to install packages with the wrong package manager... apt-get is for debian based systems when the OP is using the RPM based `yum`

Comment: The time when I added this comment it was unclear what system we are talking about. Yum was mentioned much later. That's why I stated that I'm talking bout debian.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've mentioned CentOS (at the bottom of the original question's comments)... I have no idea why "yum install" is flaking out on you but the version of git that comes with CentOS is pretty stale (1.5.x I believe), so you are best off building git from source.

Since the best place to get git source is from `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git` you have a bit of a bootstrap problem. :-)  If you can install a more modern Linux system somewhere you can grab the source, tar it up, and transfer it over to the CentOS machine and build.  Or you can grab a tarball from http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/ and build that on CentOS, then use the one you built to retrieve a current one.

Comment: with my extremely limited knowledge i found a tutorial to point to a repository that seems to let me initiate download (if I understand correctly) as part of that tutorial, I had to create a key, which seems to have been done wrong. i get this - warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6. Is there a way I can fix this as it may let me yum install it